# installed self signed certificate doesn't work

Tags: ssl, iis

Installed a self signed certificate on a web site in IIS 10 on windows server 2016. I added it to the bindings and set SSL Settings to "Accept" client certificates. When I try to pull the web site up in a browser it works without ssl, but times out when using ssl. How do I trouble shoot this?

From the request below here is the ssl test info with sensitive info changed;

BINDING: http *:80:website.com

BINDING: https *:443:website.com

SSLCertHash: hashcode

SSL Flags: None

Testing EndPoint: 127.0.0.1

#CertName: CertificateName

#Version: 3

#You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.
#Signature Algorithm: sha256RSA

#Key Exchange Algorithm: RSA Key Size: 2048
This is not an ECC certificate, so **ECDSA** cipher suites cannot be used.

#Subject: CN=servername

#Issuer: CN=servername

#Validity: From 9/23/2022 12:42:28 PM To 9/22/2023 8:00:00 PM

#Serial Number: 39eifjvif934ier93ie93id93ie93ie92i

DS Mapper Usage: Disabled

Archived: False

#Key Usage: DataEncipherment, KeyEncipherment

#Enhanced Key Usage: Server Authentication (nine numbers)
Modern web browsers require Subject Alternative Name extension to present. This certificate does not have SAN extension, so might trigger warnings and/or errors.
Certificate verified.

Comment: Did you open the browser on the same server or from another machine when "times out when using ssl"?

Comment: I tried both, neither worked.

Comment: Can you run a report to reveal more about this IIS 10 HTTPS site? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: See above edit for report.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on [sf] as it doesn't contain a programming issue. Please check for dupes before posting there.

Comment: This document is for troubleshooting SSL server certificate issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-ssl-related-issues-server-certificate

Comment: The document for trubleshooting SSL is too old. It suggests downloading the SSLDiag tool. Both links are dead. Is there something more current?